# Is there a way to make a short cut that will launch an new email message in Outlook 2003 while not in the program?

Tags: windows-xp, email, microsoft-outlook-2003

Many times I want to send a message to someone and Outlook is not the program I am in. So I have to click on Outlook, launch a new message, send it, then click to return to the program I was in when this all started. Is there a way to bypass some of those clicks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to try the command line param `/c ipm.note` in a shortcut.

Please note that for me testing this with Outlook closed it seems to leave the message in my Outbox and not send it immediately.

Source:
http://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/how-to-create-outlook-shortcuts-for-email-and-tasks/

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much. +1 plus accept. As to not sending until open, I have Outlook open at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the desktop and select New / Shortcut. In the location, type:

```
mailto:to.address@somedomain.net?Subject=Test%20Message&Cc=ccrecip@anotherplace.org&Bcc=blindkopy@foo.com
```

Let me break it down for you:

Primary Recipient Address(es)

```
mailto:to.address@somedomain.net

'?' Introduces Parameters
```

The Subject (note: spaces entered as '%20')

```
Subject=Test%20Message
```

Recipient(s) to receive 'carbon copies'

```
Cc=ccrecip@anotherplace.org
```

Recipient(s) to receive 'blind carbon copies'

```
Bcc=blindkopy@foo.com
```

You can specify multiple recipients for any of mailto:, Cc, or Bcc by separating them with semi-colons (';'). Everything after the primary recipient's address is optional. Any or all may be omitted. Also, each parameter and values must be separated by an ampersand ('&').

Finally, after entering your entire 'mailto' string in the address box, click 'Next' and name the shortcut anything you like. Finally, click 'Finish.'

When you double-click the shortcut, Windows will open a new message in your default mail client and fill the appropriate fields.

If your shortcut contains only 'mailto:' with no other information, Windows will open a new message with none of the fields filled. Also, you can do the same thing by clicking Start / Run (or Windows-key + 'R') and entering the 'mailto:' in the Run box.

Comment: I've read elsewhere on the internet that multiple email addresses in one category (eg BCC, cc or To) won't work as well as just one. Sometimes commas are better then semi-colons as dividers. Can anyone comment?